# Insert FLOAT values into mysql table

Tags: c++, mysql, floating-point, sql-insert, mysql-connector

I am trying to insert values of type FLOAT into a table using (the C++ connector is in use)

```
res = stmt->executeQuery("INSERT INTO `ticker_info`(`a1`,`a2`,`a3`,`b1`,`b2`,`b3`,`c1`,`c2`,`v1`,`v2`,`p1`,`p2`,`t1`,`t2`,`l1`,`l2`,`h1`,`h2`,`o1`) VALUES ('" + a1 + "','" + a2 + "','" + a3 + "','" + b1 + "','" + b2 + "','" + b3 + "','" + c1 + "','" + c2 + "','" + v1 + "','" + v2 + "','" + p1 + "','" + p2 + "','" + t1 + "','" + t2 + "','" + l1 + "','" + l2 + "','" + h1 + "','" + h2 + "','" + o1 + "' " );
```

The table is created as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `ac`.`ticker_info` ( `a1` FLOAT NOT NULL , `a2` INT NOT NULL , `a3` FLOAT NOT NULL , `b1` FLOAT NOT NULL , `b2` INT NOT NULL , `b3` FLOAT NOT NULL , `c1` FLOAT NOT NULL , `c2` FLOAT NOT NULL , `v1` FLOAT NOT NULL , `v2` FLOAT NOT NULL , `p1` FLOAT NO
T NULL , `p2` FLOAT NOT NULL , `t1` INT NOT NULL , `t2` INT NOT NULL , `l1` FLOAT NOT NULL , `l2` FLOAT NOT NULL , `h1` FLOAT NOT NULL , `h2` FLOAT NOT NULL , `o1` FLOAT NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

However, this fails with

```
ac.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
ac.cpp:445:161: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [132]’ and ‘float’ to binary ‘operator+’
  445 |  res = stmt->executeQuery("INSERT INTO `ticker_info`(`a1`,`a2`,`a3`,`b1`,`b2`,`b3`,`c1`,`c2`,`v1`,`v2`,`p1`,`p2`,`t1`,`t2`,`l1`,`l2`,`h1`,`h2`,`o1`) VALUES ('" + a1 + "','" + a2)  + "','" + a3 + "','" + b1 + "','" + b2 + "','" + b3 + "','" + c1 + "','" + c2 + "','" + v1 + "','" + v2 + "','" + p1 + "','" + p2 + "','" + t1 + "','" + t2 + "','" + l1 + "','" + l2 + "','" + h1 + "','" + h2 + "','" + o1 + "' " );
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~
      |                           |                                                                                                                                       |
      |                           const char [132]                                                                                                                        float
```

What I am doing wrong here? Do I really need to stringify the float values before? I would expect that I can provide the types as what they are. I searched a while for a solution but looks like I am that stupid (likely) or no one else had this issue before (unlikely).
Unfortunately the documentation hides that sucessfully too for me.

Comment: I would advice you to use **[Prepared_statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** to set parameters, and for your question, you can try with remove single quote in your sql ,such as `VALUES (" + a1 + "," + a2)`,and also seems you have a duplicate `)` in `a2)`

Comment: Noticed the duplicate ) just few secs before. Was a typo of my last test.
I already tested removing the single quotes without success. But preparing the statements and bind them later could be worth to try. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As per @lucumt recommendation perparing the statement with parameter marker and binding the values solved the issue.